# Plotting only a definite range in a dictionary and not whole length in python/matplotlib

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

Here is first of all my code :

```
 CountinmyDi = {}

        CountinmyDi = Counter(row[2] for row in rows)

        for who_id , count in CountinmyDi.most_common():
                  print(who_id,":",100float(count)/float(771))                 

        D = CountinmyDi
        xvals = range(len(D))
        xnames = D.keys()
        yvals = D.values()
        plt.bar(xvals, yvals, width=0.5, align='center')    
        plt.xticks(xvals, xnames)
        plt.xticks(range(len(D)), D.keys())
        plt.yticks(range(0,max(yvals),50))
        plt.xlim([min(xvals) - 0.5, max(xvals) + 0.5])
        plt.xticks(xvals, xnames, rotation=45)  
        plt.ylabel('test1')
        plt.title('test2')
        plt.show()
```

I am confused with the syntax how i could just plot first 10 values out of my dictionary and not the whole length of the dictionary items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's create some data from nothing

```
from numpy.random import randint
sample = randint(20, size=771)
```

Ain't we using a `Counter`?

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(str(n) for n in sample)
```

`counter.most_common` returns a list of couples, we want two lists of values from it, or in other words we want to *transpose* our data; a common idiom for that is using the `zip` builtin function

```
frequent_names, frequent_counts = zip(*counter.most_common(10))
```

To create a bar plot we need an `x` axis and the `pyplot` module (labels,titles, scaling are correct in your code so I'll skip those details)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = range(10)

plt.bar(x, frequent_counts, width=0.5, align='center')
plt.xticks(x,frequent_names)
plt.show()
```

[image]